# How to change a variable via a worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there an elegant way to do that? Or it can always be avoided because one can use a better design patter?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ForTest {

    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForTest forTest=new ForTest();
        System.out.println(forTest.ls.size());

        new Thread(new Worker(forTest.ls)).start();
        //size() does not change at all
        System.out.println(forTest.ls.size());
    }
}

class Worker implements Runnable{
    List<String> list;
    public Worker(List<String> li) {
        this.list = li;
    }

    public void run(){
        this.list.add("newItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could call `Thread.sleep(1000)` just after creating the worker and you would see that the size is increased. (Not a good idea, though.) See [assylias' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17973348/2095090)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code (in particular you use ArrayList which is not thread safe without proper synchronization).

But the most obvious one is that the second println statement is almost always going to be called *before* your `run` method has had a chance to be executed.

Comment: I am really embarrassed now. As a newbie in multithreading, I forgot to call the join() method. ..

Comment: @duleshi That would solve your problem indeed, but don't underestimate the thread safety aspect. Without appropriate synchronization, your code could look like it works, until it does not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your *main* thread `sleep()` for a while. The `size()` is getting called before the new `Thread` gets a chance to update it.

```
new Thread(new Worker(forTest.ls)).start();

Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println(forTest.ls.size());
```

An even better way would be to `join()` on to the worker thread. This would make the *main* thread automatically wake up when the *worker* is finished.

```
Thread worker = new Thread(new Worker(forTest.ls));

worker.start();
worker.join();
System.out.println(forTest.ls.size());
```

In addition to that make use of a *synchronized* `ArrayList` to prevent a race condition if the *List* would be shared and modified by multiple threads.

```
List<String> ls = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the idea of Threading.  Your code will not work because your worker has likely not updated ls by the time you print it.  If you're using threading, the threads need to communicate state.  This is all quite complex, I suggest you read the java tutorials on threading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `ArrayList` is not synchronized, but `Vector` is. You cannot expect the worker to run just a moment after you started its thread. That's why the list size is not changed yet. I guess this is not your complete example, so it is difficult to help you. (If this was your complete example I would wonder why you bother implementing a multi-threaded solution.)
For knowing when the worker finished you could [join the threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

wait for the new thread to actually start running your code + make `forTest` final to be able to access it (also use a thread-safe collection - best non-synchronous a.k.a. non-blocking) e.g.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class ForTest {

    Collection<String> ls = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ForTest forTest = new ForTest();

        System.out.println(forTest.ls.size());

        int threads = 10;

        for ( int i=0; i<threads; i++ ) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    forTest.ls.add("newItem");
                }

            }).start();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);// wait for it !

        System.out.println(forTest.ls.size()); // 10 unless your threads are really slow
    }

}
```